# Load checked checkbox and calculate them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to make that by changing the `dataFim` field or clicking on the `radio button` **Arrival** it is recalculated the *RATES AND SERVICES*.

See my code below. In this other link of the to see better all the field: https://jsfiddle.net/yormgb5j/1/

Thank you very much.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var data = new Date();
  var dia = ("0" + data.getDate()).slice(-2);
  var mes = ("0" + (data.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var ano4 = data.getFullYear();
  var hora = ("0" + data.getHours()).slice(-2);
  var min = ("0" + data.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
  var str_data = dia + '/' + mes + '/' + ano4;
  var str_hora = hora + ':' + min;




  $("input[name=situacao]").on('change', function() {

    if ($(this).val() == "S") {
      $("#data_ini").attr("readonly", true);
      $("#data_ini").attr("disabled", true);

      $('#tab-kmUsado').hide();

    } else if ($(this).val() == "C") {
      $("#data_fim").attr("readonly", true);
      $("#data_fim").attr("disabled", true);
      $("#situacao_saida").attr("disabled", false);
      $("#data_fim").val(str_data + " " + str_hora);
      $("#tab_cliente").mouseover();
      $('#tab-avisoKmUsado').hide();
      $('#tab-kmUsado').show();


      if ($("#selectPlano").val() == "KL") {
        $("#planoDia").html($("#dias").val());
        $("#planoValor").html($("#valor_dia_kmlivre").val());
        planoTotal = $("#dias").val() * $("#valor_dia_kmlivre").val();
        $("#planoTotal").html(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
        $(".planoTotal").val(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
      }

      if ($("#selectPlano").val() == "KMC") {
        $("#planoDia").html($("#dias").val());
        $("#planoValor").html($("#valor_diaria_controlada").val());
        planoTotal = $("#dias").val() * $("#valor_diaria_controlada").val();
        $("#planoTotal").html(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
        $(".planoTotal").val(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
      }

      if ($("#selectPlano").val() == "DI") {
        $("#planoDia").html($("#dias").val());
        $("#planoValor").html($("#valor_diaria").val());
        planoTotal = $("#dias").val() * $("#valor_diaria").val();
        $("#planoTotal").html(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
        $(".planoTotal").val(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
      }

      if ($("input[type=radio][name='seguroCarro']:checked").val() == "S") {
        $("#SegCarroS2").html($("#dias").val());
        $("#SegCarroS3").html($("#val_seguro_carro").val());
        seguroV = $("#dias").val() * $("#val_seguro_carro").val();
        $("#SegCarroS4").html(seguroV.toFixed(2));
        $(".SegCarroS4").val(seguroV.toFixed(2));
      } else {
        $("#SegCarroS2").html("0");
        $("#SegCarroS3").html("0");
        $("#SegCarroS4").html("0.00");
        $(".SegCarroS4").val("0.00");
      }

      if ($("input[type=radio][name='seguroTerceiros']:checked").val() == "S") {
        $("#SegTerceirosT2").html($("#dias").val());
        $("#SegTerceirosT3").html($("#val_seguro_terceiros").val());
        seguroT = $("#dias").val() * $("#val_seguro_terceiros").val();
        $("#SegTerceirosT4").html(seguroT.toFixed(2));
        $(".SegTerceirosT4").val(seguroT.toFixed(2));
      } else {
        $("#SegTerceirosT2").html("0");
        $("#SegTerceirosT3").html("0");
        $("#SegTerceirosT4").html("0.00");
        $(".SegTerceirosT4").val("0.00");
      }


      $(".recalcula").click();

    } else {

    }
  }).parent().find("input[name=situacao]:checked").change();





  $("#tab_cliente").on('mouseover', function() {
    DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    var data_ini = $("#data_ini").val().toString().split('/');
    data_ini2 = data_ini[1] + "/" + data_ini[0] + "/" + data_ini[2];
    d1 = new Date(data_ini2);

    var data_fim = $("#data_fim").val().toString().split('/');
    data_fim2 = data_fim[1] + "/" + data_fim[0] + "/" + data_fim[2];
    d2 = new Date(data_fim2);

    $("#data_ini2").val($("#data_ini").val());

    var diasLocacao = Math.round((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / DAY);

    $("#dias").val(diasLocacao);


  }).mouseover();





  $(".c").on('change', function() {

    var values = $(this).val().split('|');
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {

      var quantity = $("table[id^=tabelaIE]").length;

      $(this).data('qty', quantity);

      var table = $("#tabelaIE").clone(true)
        .attr('id', function() {
          return this.id + quantity;
        })
        .find(':text,:file')
        .attr('id', function() {
          return this.id + quantity;
        })
        .val("")
        .end();

      //VALUE -> 1|Taxa de locação|ENC|15.00|FIX|POR|VLT|%
      //$ID_ImpEnc|$nome|$tipo|$valor|$calculo|$valor_em|$aplicacao|$a

      //APLICAÇÃO: [SEG] Sobre seguro, [KML] KmLivre, [DIA] Diária, [IE] Impostos/Encargos, [VLT] no valor total
      //VALOR EM.: [MOT] Montante, [POR] Porcentagem.
      //CALCULO..: [DIA]Por dia, [FIX]Fixo
      //TIPO.....: [TXV]Taxa de Venda, [ENC]Encargos Extras

      aplicacao = values[6];
      valor_em = values[5];
      calculo = values[4];
      tipo = values[2];

      if (valor_em == "MON" && calculo == "FIX") {
        table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
        table.find('.tDias').text("1");
        table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
        tTotal = values[3] * 1;
        table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
      }

      if (valor_em == "MON" && calculo == "DIA") {
        table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
        table.find('.tDias').text($("#dias").val());
        table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
        tTotal = values[3] * $("#dias").val();
        table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
      }

      if (valor_em == "POR" && calculo == "FIX") {
        if (aplicacao == "SEG") {
          $V = (50 + 30) / 100;
          table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
          table.find('.tDias').text("1");
          table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
          tTotal = values[3] * $V;
          table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
        }
        if (aplicacao == "KML") {
          $V = values[3] / 100;
          table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
          table.find('.tDias').text("1");
          table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
          tTotal = values[3] - $V;
          table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
        }
        if (aplicacao == "DIA") {
          $V = (values[3] * $("#dias").val()) / 100;
          table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
          table.find('.tDias').text($("#dias").val());
          table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
          tTotal = values[3] * $V;
          table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
        }
        if (aplicacao == "VLT") {
          $V = $("#totalFatura").val() / 100;
          table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
          table.find('.tDias').text("1");
          table.find('.tValor').text(values[3].substring(0, 2) + "%");
          tTotal = values[3] * $V;
          table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
        }
      }



      values.forEach(function(valor, index) {
        table.find('[class="split' + (index + 1) + '"]').val(valor)
      });

      table.appendTo('#abc');

      var oldVal = $('#somaTabelaIE').val();
      $('#somaTabelaIE').val(eval(oldVal || 0) + eval(tTotal));

    } else {

      tTotal = values[3] * $("#dias").val();
      var oldVal = $('#somaTabelaIE').val();
      $('#somaTabelaIE').val(oldVal - eval(tTotal));

      //remove a table que pertence ao checkbox
      $("table#tabelaIE" + $(this).data('qty')).remove();
    }
    $(".recalcula").click();
  }).change();




});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tab_cliente"></div>
<input type="radio" class="situacao" name="situacao" id="situacao_reserva" value="R" disabled /> Reservation
<input type="radio" class="situacao" name="situacao" id="situacao_saida" value="S" checked />Output
<input type="radio" class="situacao" name="situacao" id="situacao_chegada" value="C" />Arrival

<p>
  dataIni: <input name="dataIni" type="text" id="data_ini" value="01/04/2019 08:00" /> 
  dataFim: <input name="dataFim" type="text" id="data_fim" value="03/04/2019 08:00" /> 
  DAYS: <input type="text" id="dias" style="width: 50px">
</p>

<p>===============================================</p>
Invoice total: <input type="text" id="totalFatura" value="100.00" />
<p>===============================================</p>

<strong>OPTIONS:</strong>
<div id="D1">1.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c Obrig" type="checkbox" checked value="1|Rental Rate|ENC|15.00|FIX|POR|VLT|%" alt="15.00" title="Rental Rate" /> <b> Rental Rate </b>
</div>
<div id="D2">2.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" checked value="2|GPS|ENC|5.00|DIA|MON|DIA|" alt="5.00" title="GPS" /> GPS
</div>
<div id="D3">3.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" value="3|Car wash|ENC|30.00|FIX|MON|VLT|" alt="30.00" title="Car wash" /> Car wash
</div>
<div id="D4">4.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" checked value="4|Transfer|ENC|35.00|FIX|MON|VLT|" alt="35.00" title="Transfer" /> Transfer
</div>


<p>===============================================</p>
<table width="400" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><b>RATES AND SERVICES</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="abc">
        <table id="tabelaIE" width='400' border='0'>
          <tr>
            <td class="tNome" width='190px'></td>
            <td class="tDias" width='50px' align='center'></td>
            <td class="tValor" width='60px' align='right'></td>
            <td class="tTotal" width='100px' align='right'></td>
            <td class="tValores">
              <input type="hidden" class="split1" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split2" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split3" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split4" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split5" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split6" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split7" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="split8" value="">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>===============================================</p>

SUMMARY OF RATES AND SERVICES:
<input type="text" class="somaTabelaIE" id="somaTabelaIE" value="0">
```

Comment: try to use this kind of checked condition $(this).is(':checked')

Comment: @iyyappan Which line to change?

Comment: instead of this - if ($(this).prop('checked')) {

Comment: @iyyappan Did not work

Comment: Any new suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes: Add event into change function and track event is bubble or not (property change with client click or default set in HTML tag).

Query: In uncheck logic minus total amount with multiply by number of days instead of quantity.

**Edit:** Get total value (amount * Qty) from html table which is related to checkbox (i.e unchecked checkbox).

**Edit 2:** Change method to get total amount and simplify `var Qty = $("#abc tr:contains('"+$(this).attr('title')+"') .tTotal").text();` . Edited snippet working properly.

**Edit 3:** Change Id generating Logic `var quantity = eval($("table[id^=tabelaIE]:last").attr('id').replace("tabelaIE","0"))+1`.

**Edit 4:** Change for New checkbox Output and Active Recalculations.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var data = new Date();
var dia = ("0" + data.getDate()).slice(-2);
var mes = ("0" + (data.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var ano4 = data.getFullYear();
var hora = ("0" + data.getHours()).slice(-2);
var min = ("0" + data.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
var str_data = dia + '/' + mes + '/' + ano4;
var str_hora = hora + ':' + min;




$("input[name=situacao]").on('change', function() {
    $('#somaTabelaIE').val(""); 
    $('.tTotal:visible').each(function(){ $('#somaTabelaIE').val(Number($('#somaTabelaIE').val()) + Number(this.innerHTML))})
    if ($(this).val() == "S") {
        $("#data_ini").attr("readonly", true);
        $("#data_ini").attr("disabled", true);

        $('#tab-kmUsado').hide();

    } else if ($(this).val() == "C") {
        $("#data_fim").attr("readonly", true);
        $("#data_fim").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#situacao_saida").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#data_fim").val(str_data + " " + str_hora);
        $("#tab_cliente").mouseover();
        $('#tab-avisoKmUsado').hide();
        $('#tab-kmUsado').show();


        if ($("#selectPlano").val() == "KL") {
            $("#planoDia").html($("#dias").val());
            $("#planoValor").html($("#valor_dia_kmlivre").val());
            planoTotal = $("#dias").val() * $("#valor_dia_kmlivre").val();
            $("#planoTotal").html(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
            $(".planoTotal").val(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
        }

        if ($("#selectPlano").val() == "KMC") {
            $("#planoDia").html($("#dias").val());
            $("#planoValor").html($("#valor_diaria_controlada").val());
            planoTotal = $("#dias").val() * $("#valor_diaria_controlada").val();
            $("#planoTotal").html(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
            $(".planoTotal").val(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
        }

        if ($("#selectPlano").val() == "DI") {
            $("#planoDia").html($("#dias").val());
            $("#planoValor").html($("#valor_diaria").val());
            planoTotal = $("#dias").val() * $("#valor_diaria").val();
            $("#planoTotal").html(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
            $(".planoTotal").val(planoTotal.toFixed(2));
        }

        if ($("input[type=radio][name='seguroCarro']:checked").val() =="S") {
            $("#SegCarroS2").html($("#dias").val());
            $("#SegCarroS3").html($("#val_seguro_carro").val());
            seguroV = $("#dias").val() * $("#val_seguro_carro").val();
            $("#SegCarroS4").html(seguroV.toFixed(2));
            $(".SegCarroS4").val(seguroV.toFixed(2));
        } else {
            $("#SegCarroS2").html("0");
            $("#SegCarroS3").html("0");
            $("#SegCarroS4").html("0.00");
            $(".SegCarroS4").val("0.00");
        }

        if ($("input[type=radio][name='seguroTerceiros']:checked").val() == "S") {
            $("#SegTerceirosT2").html($("#dias").val());
            $("#SegTerceirosT3").html($("#val_seguro_terceiros").val());
            seguroT = $("#dias").val() * $("#val_seguro_terceiros").val();
            $("#SegTerceirosT4").html(seguroT.toFixed(2));
            $(".SegTerceirosT4").val(seguroT.toFixed(2));
        } else {
            $("#SegTerceirosT2").html("0");
            $("#SegTerceirosT3").html("0");
            $("#SegTerceirosT4").html("0.00");
            $(".SegTerceirosT4").val("0.00");
        }


        $(".recalcula").click();

    } else {

    }
}).parent().find("input[name=situacao]:checked").change();





$("#tab_cliente").on('mouseover', function() {
    DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    var data_ini = $("#data_ini").val().toString().split('/');
    data_ini2 = data_ini[1] + "/" + data_ini[0] + "/" + data_ini[2];
    d1 = new Date(data_ini2);

    var data_fim = $("#data_fim").val().toString().split('/');
    data_fim2 = data_fim[1] + "/" + data_fim[0] + "/" + data_fim[2];
    d2 = new Date(data_fim2);

    $("#data_ini2").val($("#data_ini").val());

    var diasLocacao = Math.round((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / DAY);

    $("#dias").val(diasLocacao);


}).mouseover();



$(".c").on('change', function(e) {

    var values = $(this).val().split('|');
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {

        var quantity = eval($("table[id^=tabelaIE]:last").attr('id').replace("tabelaIE","0"))+1

        $(this).data('qty', quantity);

        var table = $("#tabelaIE").clone(true)
          .attr('id', function() {
              return this.id + quantity;
          })
          .find(':text,:file')
          .attr('id', function() {
              return this.id + quantity;
          })
          .val("")
          .end();

        //VALUE -> 1|Taxa de locação|ENC|15.00|FIX|POR|VLT|%
        //$ID_ImpEnc|$nome|$tipo|$valor|$calculo|$valor_em|$aplicacao|$a

        //APLICAÇÃO: [SEG] Sobre seguro, [KML] KmLivre, [DIA] Diária, [IE] Impostos/Encargos, [VLT] no valor total
        //VALOR EM.: [MOT] Montante, [POR] Porcentagem.
        //CALCULO..: [DIA]Por dia, [FIX]Fixo
        //TIPO.....: [TXV]Taxa de Venda, [ENC]Encargos Extras

        aplicacao = values[6];
        valor_em = values[5];
        calculo = values[4];
        tipo = values[2];

        if (valor_em == "MON" && calculo == "FIX") {
            table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
            table.find('.tDias').text("1");
            table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
            tTotal = values[3] * 1;
            table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
        }

        if (valor_em == "MON" && calculo == "DIA") {
            table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
            table.find('.tDias').text($("#dias").val());
            table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
            tTotal = values[3] * $("#dias").val();
            table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
        }

        if (valor_em == "POR" && calculo == "FIX") {
            if (aplicacao == "SEG") {
                $V = (50 + 30) / 100;
                table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
                table.find('.tDias').text("1");
                table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
                tTotal = values[3] * $V;
                table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
            }
            if (aplicacao == "KML") {
                $V = values[3] / 100;
                table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
                table.find('.tDias').text("1");
                table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
                tTotal = values[3] - $V;
                table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
            }
            if (aplicacao == "DIA") {
                $V = (values[3] * $("#dias").val()) / 100;
                table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
                table.find('.tDias').text($("#dias").val());
                table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
                tTotal = values[3] * $V;
                table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
            }
            if (aplicacao == "VLT") {
                $V = $("#totalFatura").val() / 100;
                table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
                table.find('.tDias').text("1");
                table.find('.tValor').text(values[3].substring(0, 2) + "%");
                tTotal = values[3] * $V;
                table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
            }
        }



        values.forEach(function(valor, index) {
            table.find('[class="split' + (index + 1) + '"]').val(valor)
        });

        table.appendTo('#abc');

        var oldVal = $('#somaTabelaIE').val();
        $('#somaTabelaIE').val(eval(oldVal || 0) + eval(tTotal));

    } else if(e.bubbles) {

        var Qty = $("#abc tr:contains('"+$(this).attr('title')+"') .tTotal").text();
        var oldVal = $('#somaTabelaIE').val();
        $('#somaTabelaIE').val(oldVal - eval(Qty));

        //remove a table que pertence ao checkbox
        $("table#tabelaIE" + $(this).data('qty')).remove();
    }
    $(".recalcula").click();
}).change();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab_cliente"></div>
<input type="radio" class="situacao" name="situacao" id="situacao_reserva" value="R" disabled /> Reservation
<input type="radio" class="situacao" name="situacao" id="situacao_saida" value="S" checked />Output
<input type="radio" class="situacao" name="situacao" id="situacao_chegada" value="C" />Arrival

<p>
  dataIni: <input name="dataIni" type="text" id="data_ini" value="01/04/2019 08:00" /> 
  dataFim: <input name="dataFim" type="text" id="data_fim" value="03/04/2019 08:00" /> 
  DAYS: <input type="text" id="dias" style="width: 50px">
</p>

<p>===============================================</p>
Invoice total: <input type="text" id="totalFatura" value="100.00" />
<p>===============================================</p>
<strong>OPTIONS:</strong>
<div id="D1">1.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c Obrig" type="checkbox" checked value="1|Rental Rate|ENC|15.00|FIX|POR|VLT|%" alt="15.00" title="Rental Rate" /> <b> Rental Rate </b>
</div>
<div id="D2">2.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" checked value="2|GPS|ENC|5.00|DIA|MON|DIA|" alt="5.00" title="GPS" /> GPS
</div>
<div id="D3">3.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" value="3|Car wash|ENC|30.00|FIX|MON|VLT|" alt="30.00" title="Car wash" /> Car wash
</div>
<div id="D4">4.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" checked value="4|Transfer|ENC|35.00|FIX|MON|VLT|" alt="35.00" title="Transfer" /> Transfer
</div>


<p>===============================================</p>
<table width="400" border="0">
  <tr>
<td><b>RATES AND SERVICES</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>
<div id="abc">
  <table id="tabelaIE" width='400' border='0'>
<tr>
  <td class="tNome" width='190px'></td>
  <td class="tDias" width='50px' align='center'></td>
  <td class="tValor" width='60px' align='right'></td>
  <td class="tTotal" width='100px' align='right'></td>
  <td class="tValores">
    <input type="hidden" class="split1" value="">
    <input type="hidden" class="split2" value="">
    <input type="hidden" class="split3" value="">
    <input type="hidden" class="split4" value="">
    <input type="hidden" class="split5" value="">
    <input type="hidden" class="split6" value="">
    <input type="hidden" class="split7" value="">
    <input type="hidden" class="split8" value="">
  </td>
</tr>
  </table>
</div>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>===============================================</p>

SUMMARY OF RATES AND SERVICES:
<input type="text" class="somaTabelaIE" id="somaTabelaIE" value="0">
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for helping me. I tested your code. Notice that by unchecking and redialing the checkbox, the value of the `SUMMARY OF OPTIONS` field is wrong, this is my problem.

Comment: Would it be possible to edit your post with the fix?

Comment: My system does not work. See some pictures and the error. (Open page: http://prntscr.com/n42zi8), (Clicking the checkbox: http://prntscr.com/n431j6), (Checking the checkbox again: http://prntscr.com/n432cv). I noticed that unchecking an option looks like the error in the console and does not remove it from the list; redialing it adds a new line.

Comment: `var Qty = $('tr:has(td:nth-child(1):contains("'+$(this).attr("title")+'")) .tTotal').text();` this is the line where it can causes the issue.
In above statement, total value is calculate from the fix structure like table, its attribute (i.e 'title' in our example) and its class (i.e tTotal class in our example).

Comment: How to fix this friend?

Comment: Edit post with original HTML of `IMPOSTOS` part only.

Comment: I made the update with the original code. Little has changed. Do you need some debug image from my screen?

Comment: Its better if possible to share full working jsfiddle link which are not include any demo ids nor classes (e.g id=abc in html table).

Comment: Running my friend. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I found a mistake. Click on option **1 Rental Rate**. (Unmark and mark multiple times), you will notice that the **SELECTED OPTIONS** fields disappear.

Comment: I found the error. This is the screen when loading the page (https://prnt.sc/n6wbtl). This is the other screen when unchecking and re-checkbox (https://prnt.sc/n6wc89). It is duplicating the ID.

Comment: yes that happens due to id generating part.(i.e `var quantity = $("table[id^=tabelaIE]").length;`) it causes duplicate id if deselect 1st or 2nd checkbox. because it gets length that is 3 and id of 3 is already exists. So you need to change this code by `var quantity = eval($("table[id^=tabelaIE]:last").attr('id').replace("tabelaIE","0"))+1` which get count of id's not element.

Comment: Asav, I made a change in the initial code, since I had forgotten the main fields of the beginning. See if you can help me please. I need to make that by changing the `dataFim` field or clicking on the `radio button` **Arrival** it is recalculated the **RATES AND SERVICES**.

Comment: Add this two lines in Radio button changes event.
`$('#somaTabelaIE').val("");
$('.tTotal:visible').each(function(){ $('#somaTabelaIE').val(Number($('#somaTabelaIE').val()) + Number(this.innerHTML))})`

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit your file? Thank you.